# ASP Update Panel Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I Have the following ASP Panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID = "UpdatePanel1" runat = "server">
      <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" ToolTip="The Assignment's Number" ValidationGroup="updateAssignment" AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="txtNumber_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The Script Manager is also present but the page is still doing a postback. The thing is in other pages it does not happen. I tried adding a trigger to the update panel with the control being the textbox but it still does a Postback. Please Help me Out.

Comment: I believe you are only assigning the client side `TextChanged` event, not the server side.

Comment: Can you post your script manager too? Also, what version of ASP.NET are you running?

Comment: @scottm: I believe the client-side event would be `onchange`.

Comment: @JamesJohnson In either case, I'm sure it's case sensitive.

Comment: Are you by any chance registering this as a postback control in the code-behind: `ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(txtNumber);`?

Comment: @scottm: I *think* that still works, but it's a good suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: @JeanClaudeAbela: If scottm's suggestion doesn't work, I think we'll need to see more code to help you. The code you posted should work, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: Keep `autopostback=true` on the control but add it as a `AsyncPostBackTrigger` in your `Triggers` section of your `updatepanel`.  See my answer below.

Comment: Solved it....and feeling rather dumb right now.. It seems that the script manager was not accessible by all the update panels. Sorry but its very late in the night here and I was tired. Thanks Again for your Help

Comment: Hmm that answer doesnt fit with what you posted....Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I Know. Even I was a bit baffled by it but least now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, serverside code not client side code.  The textchanged event is much different then js onchange event.  This code fires when you lose focus.  You need to set autopostback to true on the textbox but include it as a trigger:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox1" />
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As you noticed just setting the textbox to `Autopostback=true` will not work, outside of the `UpdatePanel` it will cause a postback.  However, if wrap it around an updatepanel and specify AsyncPostBackTrigger and assign the `ControlID` to the textbox in question it will work for you.  I have just tested this in chrome and IE and it works.